# Learning about subsets

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, elementary-set-theory

I have a set $A$ defined to be the power set P(X) where X is itself a nonempty set and that for the set $A$ and the relation $R$ on $A$ we have $$\forall(x,y) \in A \times A$$ $$\exists xRy$$ provided that$$ x ⊊y$$ or $$y ⊊x$$ Is the relation reflexive, symmetric and/or transitive.

My attempt: It is not reflexive because by definition the set $x \neq y$.
It is not symmetric because one of the two statements is necessarily true and the other is then necessarily not true. ie: if we have $ x ⊊y$ then we have $\exists y_{n}\in y$ such that $y_{n} \notin x$ and then $y ⊊x$ cannot be true. I believe it is transitive because if $y ⊊x$ and $z ⊊y$ then we can just say $z ⊊x$. I'm scared because of the power set and that I may have figured this wrong... Also it's hard for me to conceptualize a relation that is transitive yet isn't reflexive or symmetric.

Edit: I just realized $<$ fulfils this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the Relation $R$ is not transitive in general. For example, take $X=\{1,2\}$, then $\mathcal{P}(X)=\{\emptyset,\{1\},\{2\},X\}$. Then we have

- $\{1\}R\emptyset$ (because $\emptyset\subsetneq\{1\}$) and
- $\emptyset R\{2\}$ (because $\emptyset\subsetneq\{2\}$) but
- not $\{1\}R\{2\}$ (because $\{1\}\nsubseteq\{2\}$ and $\{2\}\nsubseteq\{1\}$),

contrary to the definition of "transitive". $R$ is not even transitive if $X=\{x\}$ for some $x$ because $\emptyset R\{x\}$ and $\{x\}R\emptyset$ (because $\emptyset\subsetneq\{x\})$ would lead to $\emptyset R\emptyset$, contradicting the reflexivity. As you have shown, $R$ is never reflexive. It is symmetric though, because of the "or" in the definition of $R$. What you have shown is that the relation $\subsetneq$ is not symmetric (but transitive). But when $xRy$ means $x\subsetneq y$ or $y\subsetneq x$, then $yRx$ means $y\subsetneq x$ or $x\subsetneq y$ and we can see that these conditions are the same, hence $xRy\Longleftrightarrow yRx$.

Comment: ah thnx I feared this would be the case. I see now I missed this counterexample.

Comment: @Christheyankee And I missed the symmetry at first too, it comes from the "or". Adding it right now

Comment: @Christheyankee Now I'm satisfied with the answer -_-

Comment: yeah after u mentioned the symmetry I thought about it and realized I missed that the or can be applied and then used that way as well haha thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it is not transitive.

You may provide a more formal proof for each part to enhance you answer but the outline is fine.

Comment: alright sweet thanks

Comment: Is it really transitive though because of the "or" in the relation?

Comment: note that $\emptyset\subsetneq\{1\}$ and $\emptyset\subsetneq\{2\}$ but $\neg \{1\}R\{2\}$, hence not transitive, right?

Comment: yeah, no. Transitive must be for all elements. And we have $\{1\}R\emptyset$ and $\emptyset R\{2\}$ but $\neg\{1\}R\{2\}$. This is why I said the "or" in the definition of $R$ might be a problem.

Comment: @S  You are correct. It has to be for all.